# Saving a Binary tree to a file in C

Tags: c, file, binary-tree

I am currently doing a Customers program when a user can add/edit/search/list customers. I decided to use a binary tree as the backbone of this program. My idea was to then save each item in the tree to "customers.dat" right before the program closes, then on start up load everything from the file to the tree. So far so good, however after finally managing to save the binary search tree into a file, I have one bug.

Lets say I add 3 customers the first time. I then close the program, and when I reopen it I will find the same 3 customers in the tree. however, the next time I open the file, it gives me an error from one of my predefined errors,  which occurs when a node is not able to identity whether to go left or right, maybe because its empty or uncomparable. here are some code snippets. I aslo tried using other fileopen techniques other than a+b, and I had no such error, but by the way I designed my program, I need the append method or else only one record will save.

Customers are stored in Cstmr in the header:

```
typedef struct customer
{
    char Name[MAXNAME];
    char Surname[MAXNAME];
    char ID[MAXID];
    char Address[MAXADDRESS];

} Cstmr;
```

else:

```
void CustomerTreeToFile(Tree*pt)
{
    if (TreeIsEmpty(pt))
        puts("Nothing to save!");
    else
        Traverse(pt,saveItem); //Traverses each node, and appliess the function 
                                   //saveItem to each node
}

void saveItem(Cstmr C)
{
    save = C;
    customers = fopen("customers.dat","ab+");
    fwrite(&C,sizeof (Cstmr), 1, customers);
    fclose(customers);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure where the bug might be, but... In general, you really don't want to be opening and closing a file a bunch of times. You really want to open the file once, and pass the pointer to it to the Traverse, and subsequently saveItem, functions. File operations are incredibly slow, so do them as little as possible.

Comment: Try tracking how the file changes between the time when opening it work, and the time it does not.

Comment: Tried it. I've put fopen and fclose once at the main(), still the same problem :/

Comment: Side note: please try to choose one naming convention and stick with it. If you write functions `likeThis`, `LikeThis` or `like_this`, always use the same method (`saveItem` vs `CustomerTreeToFile` or `Surname` vs `ID`). Also, a name like `This` is usually used as a `struct` name (not member variable for example) and a name like `THIS` is used for macros.

Comment: Side note 2: When using `sizeof`, try to get the size of the relevant type from the variables rather than types. For example, in `fwrite` you could use `sizeof(customers[0])`. That way, if you change the type `Cstmr` to another name, or if you change the type of `customers` to another type, you don't need to change the `sizeof`.

Comment: Side note 3: Not visible from the code, but just in case your tree is a balanced binary tree, you might want to consider implementing `Traverse` as BFS. In this way, when reconstructing the tree, the tree would automatically be balanced. (a not so important optimization, but thought you may find it interesting)

Comment: thanks for these side notes, I tend to get a little clumsy with names when I'm creating new functions while trying to find a solution. Also yes, this is a BST and it traverses the tree root, left, right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are always appending all the data to the same file ... so everything from the previous run is duplicated.

One solution would be to delete (unlink) the file before saving the data with your current approach.

However, as Freezerburn pointed out earlier, it's more economic to not open and close the file for each item. Just open the file once in overwrite mode (i.e. not append), then write all the data, then close the file. Should be much faster, too.

Another problem is that you save your data in binary format. Try to define an easy to read textual format. That would have made the problem obvious ...

Comment: For this particular assignment, a binary storage file is needed. I've thought of overwriting the file, hence the reason why I changed fopen types from a+b. however as I've said, Im traversing the tree and saving individual items, therefore I would need to append the file. How could I delete the file before writing?

Comment: Never mind, problem solved :) It may be a little unprofessional, but at least it works. right before I saved, I Fopened and Fclosed a file with "wb". 

    DelCustomer = fopen("customers.dat","wb");
    fclose(DelCustomer);